# Is there a way to use Ngx-Charts with Aurelia framework?

Tags: aurelia, ngx-charts

I want to use some of the charts by ngx-chart in my Aurelia application, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use `ngx-chart` within an Aurelia application but to make it work, you will need to bring in the whole runtime of Angular to support it, and it's not going to be small. You can use a dedicated charting library like Chart.js https://www.chartjs.org/ or use a wrapper https://github.com/grofit/aurelia-chart for it.